# Are only items listed in backup descriptors backed up?

Tags: android

So the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#IncludingFiles) doesn't make it clear to me whether only items explicitly listed in a backup descriptor `xml` are backed up. Say I add the following.

```
<include
    domain="database"
    path="data.db" />
```

Will that database file be the only item being backed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#IncludingFiles):

> `<include>` - Specifies a file or folder to backup. By default, Auto
>   Backup includes almost all app files. If you specify an 
>   element, the system no longer includes any files by default and backs
>   up only the files specified. To include multiple files, use multiple
>   `<include>` elements.

So, once you specify **include** the files that would be backed up by default are no longer backed up.

---

Yup, only that database file will be backed up in that specification you have there.